# Adding multiple sections dynamically -ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, architecture, asp.net-4.0, jquery-templates

I have a web page which has a non determined number of sections (made up of a collection of textbox, dropdowns etc). A user clicks on "Add Section" button and this section should be added dynamically. There is no upper limit on how many sections a user can add. There is then a Save button at which time the I need to traverse through all the sections and persist the data.

My first thought is to create the section as a user control that I dynamically add whenever a user clicks on the "Add section" on the server side.

I'd like to avoid doing adding user controls dynamically as I feel it's a little quirky. I am trying to understand if I can leverage jquery or client templates for the use case here.

Thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: We have an app similar to this which we handle by a hybrid approach. Usercontrols are used when the page loads the first time and dynamic client side rendering is handled by jQuery templates. It is all possible because we do not use postbacks at all, but used jQuery bajax to the WebMethods for talking to the server. SWo yes, this would work!

Comment: Floyd - Can you explain the hybrid approach? Are you saying that the first time the page loads, you add the existing sections as user controls. Any subsequent adds, you'd grab the markup from the user control and use jquery templates to render the section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any wrong in using user control solution. A similar (server side) technique would be to use a data-bound control such as Repeater or ListView - the item template would define the section. The advantage with server side solution is that it can be quickly built and can use ASP.NET infrastructure such as view-state (so that you don't have to worry about maintaining state on post-backs). Typical ASP.NET Forms developer would easily understand the logic. Flip side is that larger markup size, multiple large data transfers while adding sections (whether you use full or partial post-back will not matter much - view-state will be significant part of data being transfer).

I will personally prefer client templating approach because you avoid post-backs and associated data transfers. But there are two issues - a) relatively complex logic for displaying/updating sections - remember your code is fragmented at two places - js and server side code - typical developers would find it difficult to understand b) reliance of java-script (sometime, you must provide for a fallback mechanism if js is not supported)